# Ember Data: resolve ambiguous inverses when using multiple belongsTo relationships between two models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Say I have two Ember Data models: `competition` and `participant`

My competition model stores the following data: `date`, `first`, `second` and `third`. The `first`, `second` and `third` properties will all store IDs of the unique competitors who came in first, second and third place.

My `participant` model stores the following data: `name`, `surname` and `competition`

Participants only compete in one competition, so the `participant` model doesn't need a `hasMany` relationship on `competition`.

**How do I model this in Ember Data?**

Here's what I thought might work:

```
// app/models/competition.js

export default DS.Model.extend({
  rev: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.attr('date', {defaultValue: function() { return new Date(); }}),
  first: DS.belongsTo('participant'),
  second: DS.belongsTo('participant'),
  third: DS.belongsTo('participant')
});

// app/models/participant.js

export default DS.Model.extend({
  rev: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  surname: DS.attr('string'),
  competition: DS.belongsTo('competition')
});
```

The problem is that the `competition` key on `participant.js` requires an explicit inverse, and there's no way of knowing which of the three keys on `competition` it may relate to.

How should I be specifying my inverses? Do both the `competition` and `participant` models require explicit inverses? If so, what should they be? Is this kind of data structure even possible in Ember Data? Should I use a different approach altogether?

Please weigh in. I've turned this problem around in my head for hours, and none of my workarounds have succeeded.

Comment: What does your response json look like?

Comment: There's no JSON to speak of. I'm using PouchDB, so I don't need to serialize anything. When I look in the localstorage database, all belongsTo fields are null.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ember-data polymorphic association myself, but I believe a polymorphic belongsTo association might suit your needs. My answer is adapted from this [blog post](http://www.codingepiphany.com/2014/08/18/simplistic-explanation-emberdata-polymorphism/)
. Also check this two tutorials: http://www.toptal.com/emberjs/a-thorough-guide-to-ember-data and http://blog.unspace.ca/post/107228551852/luke-galea-on-ember-data-polymorphic-associations

```
 //app/models/competition.js
 export default DS.Model.extend({
   rev: DS.attr('string'),
   date: DS.attr('date', {defaultValue: function() { return new Date(); }}),
   participant: DS.belongsTo("particpant", {polymorphic: true,   async: true})
  });

 // app/models/participant.js
 export default DS.Model.extend({
   rev: DS.attr('string'),
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   surname: DS.attr('string'),
   competition: DS.belongsTo('competition')
 });

 // app/models/first.js
 import Participant from '../participant';
 export default Participant.extend({
 });

 // app/models/second.js
 import Participant from '../participant';
 export default Participant.extend({
 });
```

Comment: I'll test this solution over the weekend and let you know if it worked for me. Thanks for providing this suggestion. My current solution was simply to flatten the competitor model and migrate all the keys for all three competitors to the competition model. It's an ugly hack and I hope there's a better way.